# React Not Rerendering After Redirect

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I am a begginer to React Js and I'm facing some issues with it. I'm working on a test application where the signed in user can delete his/her post when pressing the delete button, where he/she is redirected to a route that only shows the pop up modal with a confirmation message (I am using react portals for that).

When the user deletes the post, he/she is redirected back to the page that had all the posts, but the deleted post is visible until the user reloads the page, that's when it disappears, I can't seem to find a solution to this.I thought React was supposted to rerender but that doesnot seem to happen .Here is a code snippet for that

**REACT**

```
 <button
      onClick={() => this.props.deleteStream(id)}
      className="ui negative button"
    >
      Delete
    </button>
    <button onClick={() => history.push("/")} className="ui button">
      Cancel
    </button>
```

**REDUX(ACTION)**

```
export const deleteStream = id => {
  return async dispatch => {
    await streams.delete(`/streams/${id}`);
    history.push("/");
    return dispatch({ type: DELETE_STREAM, payload: id });
  };
};
```

I am using lodash to create a new object which updates when the user deletes the post with the specified ID

**REDUX(REDUCER)**

```
 case DELETE_STREAM:
  return _.omit(state, "id");
```

Comment: I am assuming that `streams.delete(`/streams/${id}`);` does not produce an error since the stream is gone when you refresh. Maybe something goes wrong in the reducer for `DELETE_STREAM`. Can you update the question with the reducer code handling that action? (oh yea, and welcome to Stack overflow)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest using modern JavaScript to remove a key from an object.

You are using [omit](https://lodash.com/docs/#omit) wrong and deleting a key named "id" but I think the key **is** the id and you should use `return _.omit(state, action.payload);`

But better to not bother with loadash and use JS

```
return Object.fromEntries(
  Object.entries(state).filter(([key])=>key!==action.payload)
)
```

You can put that in a library function if you plan to use that more often.

Comment: I replaced the id with action.payload and it seems to be working fine. I will be looking forward to implement the new syntax

Comment: @KelvinMitaki Maybe instead of using lodash you can try [this utility](https://gist.github.com/amsterdamharu/659bb39912096e74ba1c8c676948d5d9) to modify state without mutating it